# How do I plot list of lines represented as tuples in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Suppose, I have a Python function which returns the detected lines from a method named `marching_square()`.

Say, I have the following data set.  I would like to use MatPlotLib to plot the data.

The tuples are of the form `(x1, y1, x2, y2)`.

```
 [(20.0, 10, 20, 10.0), (20, 10.0, 30, 10.0),
(30, 10.0, 40, 10.0), (40.0, 10, 40, 10.0),
(70.0, 10, 70, 10.0), (70, 10.0, 80, 10.0),
(80, 10.0, 90, 10.0), (90.0, 10, 90, 10.0),
(10.0, 20, 10, 20.0), (10.0, 20, 20, 10.0),
(20.0, 10, 10, 20.0), (20, 10.0, 30, 10.0),
(30, 10.0, 40, 10.0), (50.0, 20, 40, 10.0),
(40.0, 10, 50, 20.0), (50, 20.0, 60, 20.0),
(60.0, 20, 70, 10.0), (70.0, 10, 60, 20.0),
(70, 10.0, 80, 10.0), (80, 10.0, 90, 10.0),
(100.0, 20, 90, 10.0), (90.0, 10, 100, 20.0),
(10.0, 20, 10, 20.0), (20.0, 30, 10, 20.0),
(10.0, 20, 20, 30.0), (20.0, 30, 20, 30.0),
(40.0, 30, 40, 30.0), (40.0, 30, 50, 20.0),
(50.0, 20, 40, 30.0), (50, 20.0, 60, 20.0),
(70.0, 30, 60, 20.0), (60.0, 20, 70, 30.0),
(70.0, 30, 70, 30.0), (100.0, 30, 100.0, 20),
(20.0, 30, 20, 30.0), (30.0, 40, 20, 30.0),
(20.0, 30, 30, 40.0), (30.0, 40, 40, 30.0),
(40.0, 30, 30, 40.0), (40.0, 30, 40, 30.0),
(70.0, 30, 70, 30.0), (80.0, 40, 70, 30.0),
(70.0, 30, 80, 40.0), (80, 40.0, 90, 40.0),
(90.0, 40, 100, 30.0), (100.0, 30, 90, 40.0)]
```

How can this be done?

---

```
example = np.array([
                    [ 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0],
                    [ 0,0, 1, 1, 1, 0,0,1,1,1,0 ],
                    [ 0,1, 0, 0, 0, 1,1,0,0,0,1 ],
                    [ 0,0, 1, 0, 1, 0,0,1,0,0,1 ],
                    [ 0,0, 0, 1, 0, 0,0,0,1,1,0 ]
                ]);

x = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100];
y = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40];

collection = marching_square(x, y, example, 1);

for ln in collection:
    for toup in ln:
        line = list(toup)
        plt.plot(line)
        
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the `x1, y1, x2, y2` of each tuple and then create both the rectangle edges and fill:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

collection = [(20, 10, 20, 10), (20, 10, 30, 10), (30, 10, 40, 10), (40, 10, 40, 10), (70, 10, 70, 10), (70, 10, 80, 10), (80, 10, 90, 10), (90, 10, 90, 10), (10, 20, 10, 20), (10, 20, 20, 10), (20, 10, 10, 20), (20, 10, 30, 10), (30, 10, 40, 10), (50, 20, 40, 10), (40, 10, 50, 20), (50, 20, 60, 20), (60, 20, 70, 10), (70, 10, 60, 20), (70, 10, 80, 10), (80, 10, 90, 10), (100, 20, 90, 10), (90, 10, 100, 20), (10, 20, 10, 20), (20, 30, 10, 20), (10, 20, 20, 30), (20, 30, 20, 30), (40, 30, 40, 30), (40, 30, 50, 20), (50, 20, 40, 30), (50, 20, 60, 20), (70, 30, 60, 20), (60, 20, 70, 30), (70, 30, 70, 30), (100, 30, 100, 20), (20, 30, 20, 30), (30, 40, 20, 30), (20, 30, 30, 40), (30, 40, 40, 30), (40, 30, 30, 40), (40, 30, 40, 30), (70, 30, 70, 30), (80, 40, 70, 30), (70, 30, 80, 40), (80, 40, 90, 40), (90, 40, 100, 30), (100, 30, 90, 40)]

for x1, y1, x2, y2 in collection:
    plt.plot([x1, x1, x2, x2, x1], [y1, y2, y2, y1, y1])
    plt.fill([x1, x1, x2, x2, x1], [y1, y2, y2, y1, y1], alpha=0.3)
plt.show()
```

[image: rectangles]

The given example seems to contain some rectangle with zero height.